# Reading and Writing Data to XML

Tags: c#, xml

I have been tinkering with this project for a while and I've run into a brick wall. This is my very first project and I'm really not sure where to go from here. I was trying my hardest to read up on what the next step is so I wouldn't have to post on here again, but it seems I have little choice.

Anyway, here is a brief explanation on what I am trying to accomplish with this project. I am trying to retrieve certain values from three elements in an already existing XML document. After I have loaded each value for each element into it's respective text box, I am then trying to save any changes to the values into the document. (Easier said that done!)

I am using XDocument to store the values into a list and then display them to their text boxes.

I can't figure out how to update changes back to the original values and save. So far trying to save leaves me with a blank XML document and crashes my application. :\

Here is the XML data that I can read and display:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1:8086">
  <endpoint address="http://127.0.0.1:8084">
  <endpoint address="net.tcp://127.0.0.1:8085">
</client>
```

And here is some of the code that I have written thus far.

```
    OpenFileDialog AgentConfig = new OpenFileDialog();

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        AgentConfig.Filter = "Agent.exe.config (*.config)|*.config";
        if (AgentConfig.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            textBox1.Text = AgentConfig.FileName;
        }

        var addresses = XDocument.Load(AgentConfig.FileName)
                     .Descendants("endpoint")
                     .Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("address"))
                     .ToList();

        textBox2.Text = addresses[0];
        textBox3.Text = addresses[1];
        textBox4.Text = addresses[2];

        if (textBox2.Text != addresses[0])
        {
            addresses[0] = textBox2.Text;
        }

        if (textBox3.Text != addresses[1])
        {
            addresses[1] = textBox3.Text;
        }

        if (textBox4.Text != addresses[2])
        {
            addresses[3] = textBox4.Text;
        }


    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog SF = new SaveFileDialog();
        if (SF.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

        }
    }
```

Any help would definitely be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could make your life really easy and make a `Client` class with a `List<Address>()` and then look into XML Serialization, otherwise, is any data actually retrieved? where is the error, I'd imagine you need `x.Attribute("address").Value`

Comment: Since the `endpoint`s don't have any kind of id to differentiate one from the other, you probably need to save all three values each time. `var client = new XElement("client", new XElement("endpoint", new XAttribute("address", textBox2.Text)), new XElement("endpoint", new XAttribute("address", textBox3.Text)), new XElement("endpoint", new XAttribute("address", textBox4.Text)));`. Then open the xml, find the previous `client` node, remove it from its parent and add the new `client` to that parent and save.

Comment: Forgot to point out, your textboxes never won't equal the addresses since you assign the text to the address

Comment: Sayse: Yes the data is retreived. Issue is trying to save back to the XML any changes made to the values.

Corak: Would that work at all? Seems like it might just replace the first address value three different times.

Comment: Why do you think it would replace the first address value three different times?

Comment: Corak: Not sure... I really don't know what it will do, lol. I suppose I can give it a shot though. Thank you.

Comment: When in doubt, refer to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb302741.aspx) ^_^. The constructor of XElement takes an arbitrary number of objects and tries to create child elements or attributes for each of them.

Comment: Corak: Thanks for the help! So far SO has proven to be the best way to get assistance!

Answer (score 1):

```
var xElem = new XElement("client",
    new XElement("endpoint", new XAttribute("address", textBox2.Text)),
    new XElement("endpoint", new XAttribute("address", textBox3.Text)),
    new XElement("endpoint", new XAttribute("address", textBox4.Text)));

xElem.Save(filename);
```

Comment: Simple and effective. I know I should be using classes and different ways to extract, store, display, and save my data, but this is my very first project and I'm aiming for a quick and dirty way of slapping this together. This worked brilliantly!

Answer (score 0):

One approach could be to use the following classes:

```
class System.Data.DataSet
```

Represents an in-memory cache of data, see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx)

```
class System.IO.StramWriter
```

Implements a TextWriter for writing characters to a stream in a particular encoding, see [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Go then like this:

```
DataSet ds = newDataSet();
CreateMyDataSet("your arguments"); // Create your DataSet according to your xml-format
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(SaveFileDialog.FileName, ...);
sw.Write(ds.GetXml());  // GetXml() returns the xml representation of your data
sw.Close();
```

Comment: I will look into this a little bit more. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

try Using a Xml writer to save. Here is a link fot you

[a link]http://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlwriter

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely look into it.